# Как обратиться к POST методу через ссылку ASP.NET CORE

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net, asp.net-core

Я новичок в asp.net core, и вот у меня появился вопрос: как я могу обратиться к POST методу Logout через ссылку?

Изначально делал так, но очевидно, что это неверно, ибо таким путем я пытаюсь обратиться именно к GET методу, который в данном контексте не существует:

`<a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout"><i class="mdi mdi-power"></i></a>`

Если я правильно понимаю, то сделать это можно только через AJAX запрос и "onclick", но в этом я пока что очень зеленый и мало что понимаю.

P.S. Через `<form>` и `<button>` не устроит, нужна именно ссылка:(

P.S.S. На всякий случай реализация метода Logout:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: А переделать Logout через GET не вариант?

Comment: @ГеннадийП Совершенно не вариант, это же классическая дырка в безопасности. Подобным образом наказывали допустим веб-мастеров которые объявлял через GET метод удаления поста - просто постили невидимые ссылки которые сносили пользователям нафиг все посты - просто перебором айдишников. Не стоит открывать дверь в эту сторону, в нехорошие места ведёт. И топикстартеру не советую. Учите лучше ajax.

Comment: @AK Понял, принял.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core - Log In and Log Out](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_log_in_and_log_out.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Решено! Колхоз ли? Наверное, да. Но меня спасло

```
<form
  method="post"
  id="form1"
  asp-controller="Account"
  asp-action="Logout"
></form>
<a
  onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit(); return false;"
  href="#"
  data-toggle="tooltip"
  title="Logout"
  ><i class="mdi mdi-power"></i>
</a>
```